# If $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n - b_n| = 1$ and $ a_n$ is bounded, does that make $b_n$ bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \lvert a_n - b_n \rvert  = 1$$

and $a_n$ is bounded, does that make $b_n$ bounded?

Could you provide an example for 2 sequences?

Comment: Show $|b_n|\le |a_n|+1$.

Comment: How did you get it to show the formulas?

Comment: Indeed, it is sufficient for $|a_n - b_n|$ to be bounded (it doesn't even need to converge).

Comment: You gentlemen are amazing, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|a_n|\leq B$ for some $B>0$.

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |a_n-b_n|=1$, so there exists some $m\geq 1$ where if $n\geq m$ then
$$|(a_n-b_n)-1|<1$$
$$\Rightarrow -1<a_n-b_n-1<1$$
$$\Rightarrow 0< a_n-b_n <2$$
$$\Rightarrow 0 < a_n-b_n$$
$$\Rightarrow b_n < a_n \leq B$$

So if $n\geq m$ then $b_n \leq B$. Then for $1\leq n< m,$
$$b_n \leq \max\{b_1,\dots,b_{m-1}\}.$$

So for all $n\geq 1$
$$b_n \leq \max\{b_1,\dots,b_{m-1},B\}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Observe the triangle inequality: $|b_n| \leq |b_n-a_n| + |a_n| \leq M + N$.

Comment: Can you please give a bit more details on this? Sorry...

Comment: Convergent sequence is bounded, so $|a_n-b_n|$ is bounded by $M$.

Comment: If I understood correctly, than: This means that 1 + |b_n| is greater than | b_n | hence b_n is bounded?

Comment: That is not true.

Comment: I am sorry if my questions are trivial, I am having difficulty with Infinitesimal. I know that a_n is convergent sequence, but how can I distinctly show that be is convergent as well?

Comment: Got it, thanks.